# nodeschool exercise solving with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I was solving nodeschool exercise "Juggling Async" and i solved it like this

```
var http=require("http");
var urls=process.argv.slice(2,process.argv.length);
var count=0;
var junge=[];
urls.map(function(url,index){
http.get(url,function(response){
    var str="";
    response.setEncoding("utf-8");

    response.on("data",function(data){str=str+data})
    response.on("end",function(){
        junge.push(str);
        count++;
        if(index==urls.length-1) junge.map(function(v){console.log(v)})

    });

});})
```

(it works) but i was thinking how would this exercise looked like if i used promises?
I tried to do it like this

```
var http=require("http");
var urls=process.argv.slice(2,process.argv.length);
var count=0;
var fin=[];
var promise=function(x){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        http.get(x,function(response){
            response.setEncoding("utf-8");
            var junge=[];
            response.on("data",function(data){
                junge.push(data);
            });
            response.on("end",function(){
                resolve(junge)
            })
        })

    }
        )
    }
    function printitfgt(x){
        var m=promise(x);
        return m.then(function(response){
            fin.pus(response)
                    })
    }
urls.forEach(function(x,index){
    printitfgt(x);
    if(index==urls.length-1) console.log(fin)
})
```

But this code does not pass an  expectation and simply says i failed. In that case i assume this code does not work or has some bug in it which i fail to see. What would be the sulution with promises then?

Answer (score 0):

**Erazihel** is right, you're missing `reject`. As to how I would wrap this with promises, I would put as little code inside the Promise constructor executor function as possible, e.g. do the minimal drop-in that fills the absence of a function that supports promises.

Also, I see no reason not to use `Promise.all` to do the urls in parallel (faster):

```
Promise.all(urls.map(function(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var str = "";
    http.get(url, function(response) {
      response.on("data", function(data) { str+=data; });
      response.on("end", function() { resolve(str); });
      response.error("end", function() { reject(str); });
    });
  });
}))
.then(function(junge) {
  console.log(junge);
})
.catch(function(e) { console.log(e); });
```

I would also look at using [`fetch`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-api), if that is available.

```js
var console = { log: function(msg) { div.innerHTML += msg + "<br>"; }};
var http = { get: function(u, f) {
  f({ on: function(name, f) { f(name == "data" && u); }});
}};
var urls=["result1", "result2"];

Promise.all(urls.map(function(url,index) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var str = "";
    http.get(url, function(response) {
      response.on("data", function(data) { str+=data; });
      response.on("end", function() { resolve(str); });
      response.error("end", function() { reject(str); });
    });
  });
}))
.then(function(junge) {
  console.log(junge);
})
.catch(function(e) { console.log(e); });
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```